# ASP.net Hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed asp.net website using c# and MVC architecture. Any Suggestion about Where should I upload it? On which web hosting website? I am new to web application. Also need help on which features should I look for before selecting any hosting services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Hosting Checklist (There are lots of checklist available, you can search google for more details)

1. Disk space
2. Bandwidth
3. Domains
4. Programming language
5. Email accounts
6. E-commerce options
7. a decent management Panel
8. a decent technical support
9. Flexibility
10. extra service
11. a strong infrastructure

Check these checklist:

[Web Hosting Checklist](http://www.webpagemistakes.ca/web-hosting-checklist/)

[Web Hosting Checklist](http://www.jckh.org/56-web-hosting-checklist.html)